# How to change standard input from console to another program in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am trying to create a program that parses data received from another program.  Once the program is built, I could do something like this:

```
./someprogram -pipe | ./my_program -file saveFile.txt
```

As I am making my program in Eclipse, is there a way I can debug/run my program so that standard input  is taken from the other program instead of the console?

A workaround could be to do something like this:

```
./someprogram -pipe > testFile.txt
./my_program -infile testFile.txt -outfile saveFile.txt
```

The problem with this is I cannot deal with real time data while I build my program.

Any solutions?

Comment: "The problem with this is I cannot deal with real time data while I build my program."  explain what you mean by "real time data".

Comment: The other program grabs sensor data and logs it.  The "-pipe" argument also pipes the data out standard output.  I want to be able to handle sensor drop outs and the like by sending commands via UDP to fix those problems.  That is why I would like to be able to build/debug in real time.

Comment: Does the **Common** tab of the C++ launch configuration not allow you to set a file as the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a script to do the piping:

```
#!/bin/bash

./someprogram -pipe | ./my_program -file saveFile.txt
```

Remember to make your script executable:

```
$ chmod u+x ./my_script.sh
```

Then go to menu `Run -> Run configurations...`

Create a new run configuration and select your script under `C/C++Application` using the `Browse` button.

Comment: For those who want the script exactly for debugging: "./someprogram -pipe | ./Debug/my_program -file saveFile.txt"

Answer (score 0):

An input file can be set in the run/debug configuration:

1. ***Run > Run Configurations...***
2. In the tab ***Common*** check ***Input File*** and enter or select the `testFile.txt` file

Answer (score -1):

You can simply feed your program with input redirect:

`./my_program < testFile.txt > saveFile.txt`

Comment: Can I do that from Eclipse?  In the arguments tab?

Comment: You may want to add to your answer suggestions on how to do this with eclipse's console.